# Поиск по сайу

Tags: php

В базе несколько тысяч новостей. Сайт-самопис
Какой поисковик использовать лучше всего? Может, есть нормальные готовые решения...
самопальный поиск с использованием MATCH AGAINST или LIKE не советуют )

Answer (score 1):

SPHINX! Главное не плюнте на него из за того что не поняли его, и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0):

Как на счет почитать что-то типа этого:

- [Пишем собственное поисковое ядро. 1](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1264)
- [Пишем собственное поисковое ядро. 2](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1265).